# How to handle double lastnames in latex bibtex

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I have an author name of an article, P de Jong, which I would like to reference in Latex as

> Jong, P. de , [article name].

Can someone give me an example code for how to do so?

Answer (score 6):

The "correct" solution depends on several factors. As I will demonstrate, what you appear to be interested in is the "Dutch" bibliography style. Do read on.

- Most bibliography styles -- but see below for the main exception: the so-called "Dutch" style -- automatically place the "von" component ahead of the "lastname" component. Hence, if one writes

  ```
  author = "Paul de Jong",
  ```

  or

  ```
  author = "Casper de Vries",
  ```

  or [!]

  ```
  author = "Vincent van Gogh",
  ```

  the "von" component will be placed ahead of the surname.
- How does BibTeX identify the "von" component of the full name? By default, if the full name is entered in the `author` field in `first-von-last-jr` ordering, the "von" component is taken to consist of the words that start with lowercase letters:

  ```
  Walter von der Vogelweide: "von der"
  Peter von zur Muehlen:     "von zur"
  ```

  etc.
- If you're dealing with von components that start with uppercase letters, though, you need to provide an override. In fact, when it comes to names such as "Dominique Von Matt" and "Pasquale Della Corte", it's actually becoming a bit academic to argue whether "Von" and "Della" are the "von" components of the full names or, alternatively, parts of a two-word surname. Either way, you should enter the names as

  ```
  Von Matt, Dominique
  Della Corte, Pasquale
  ```

  That way, BibTeX will happily (and correctly...) think that the full names consist of a two-word surname and a single first name.
- The same goes for full names where the true surname consists of two (or more) separate names. Some examples:

  ```
  Scott Thomas, Kristin
  Garcia Pascual, Antonio
  Mies van der Rohe, Ludwig (it would be wrong to treat "Mies" as a first name!)
  ```

  Note that there's no "von" component in these names.
- Finally, let's turn to the so-called "Dutch" exception: A huge number of (full) Dutch names contain the "von" components "de" and "van" (or "van de", "van den", "van der", etc). If you're writing in Dutch for a Dutch publication, it's customary to sort all entries by the *surname component only*, i.e., not to include the "de" and "van" particles. Otherwise, I suppose, a rather large subset of all entries would be sorted under "D" and "V", respectively...

  If you need to apply the "Dutch" bibliography style, I suggest you start by employing the `nederlands` bibliography style. It is part of the `harvard` citation management package.

A full MWE -- observe that "Gogh" is listed before "Vries", and that that citation callouts provide the 'von' components.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@misc{abc,author="Vincent van Gogh", title="Sunflowers",   year=1888}
@misc{def,author="Casper G. de Vries",  title="Econometrics", year=1992}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{harvard}
\bibliographystyle{nederlands}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\cite{abc}, \cite{def}
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: If you need to list the entries in the bibliography as "Jong, P. de" rather than as "Paul de Jong" (which is the default setting in the `nederlands` bibliography style), I suggest you proceed as follows:

- Find the file `nederlands.bst` in your TeX distribution.
- Make a copy of this file and call the copy, say, `mynederlands.bst`. (Don't edit an original file of the TeX distribution directly.)
- Open the file `mynederlands.bst` in a text editor. The program you use to edit your tex files will do fine.
- In `mynederlands.bst`, locate the function `format.names`. (It starts on line 326 in my copy of the file.) In this function, locate the line

  ```
      { s nameptr "{ff~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=
  ```

  In this line, change `"{ff~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}"` to `"{ll}{, jj}{, f.}{ vv}"`.

  Basically, this change serves to (a) place the surname component first, to abbreviate any given names, and to place the "von" component last.
- Locate the function `format.crossref.editor`. (It should start around line 690). In this function, change the string `"{ff }{vv }{ll}{ jj}"` to `"{ll}{, jj}{, f.}{ vv}"`.
- Save the file `mynederlands.bst` either in the directory where your main tex file is located or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the second option, be sure to update the filename database of your TeX distribution suitably.
- In your main tex file, change the instruction `\bibliographystyle{nederlands}` to `\bibliographystyle{mynederlands}` and perform a full recompile (latex-bibtex-latex-latex).

A revised MWE:

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@misc{abc, author="Vincent van Gogh", title="Sunflowers", year=1888}
@misc{def, author="Casper G. de Vries", title="Econometrics", year=1992}
@misc{ghi, author="Paul de Jong", title="Thoughts", year=3001}
@misc{jkl, author="Skander van den Heuvel", title="Risk Management", year=2005}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{harvard}
\bibliographystyle{mynederlands}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\cite{abc}, \cite{def}, \cite{ghi}, \cite{jkl}
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the comprehensive answer! However, I prefer using the apacite package in combination with the natbib package. I tried changing the format names function as you suggested, however this does not put the author's name in the right order. What should I change in the apacite.bst file in order to get 'Paul de Jong' referenced as 'Jong, P. de'?

Comment: @Esmee - And how was I supposed to know which citation package (`apacite`) you prefer to use? Incidentally, you should under absolutely no circumstance load both the `apacite` package *and* the `natbib` package. If you use the `apacite` package and would like to use the natbib-based commands `\citet` and `\citep`, you should load the `apacite` package with the option `natbibapa`. And, if you load the `apacite` package, you should really be using the `apacite` bibliography style. If you have questions about how to go about modifying the `apacite` bibliography style, please post a new query.